# Best way to show large amount of data

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

What is the best way to handle a large amount of data entries on a web page? 
Let's assume I am having a database with 5000 records on a table that contain song_name,author_name,song_id,posted_by; I want to build a playlist with all the songs on a single page. Also on that page there is a *player* that plays songs according to the playlist entries that is shown on the page. 
I have tried to pull all 5000 entries from that table and build a javascript object with them, and handling that object I have built the playlist, search in playlist, and so forth. But that takes a very large amount of resources ( un the user end ) and a lot of page loading time ( because there are a lot of entries! ) and the page is very slow. 
Is it better to load all the data into an object and paginate by **JavaScript** each 100 records of the playlist or is it better to *get the results paginated from the database* and just update the playlist? ( **This taking in consideration the fact that I if the player has the *shuffle* button activated, it may shuffle to ANY song in the user's database, not only on the current songs from the visible playlist** )

Comment: You get a paginated response from the server of course.

Comment: yes u cant be getting 5000 records at once and load them all into local memory..I'd get paginated results from the server. If the shuffle mode is on and the next song is not in the local list then fetch it from the server.

Comment: But first of all I need to get all the rows from the server and build the "entire" playlist for the shuffle option. After that is it better to get paginated entries? It wouldn't be more fast if I just get results from the jquery object that is already created and I just set the pagination offset and update the page html?

Comment: I would use the LIMIT functionality of MySQL and increment the index on each call.

Comment: @SajjanSarkar I see. So it's better to get the entries count, and if shuffle mode is active then I just get a random entry between 0 and count; and then fetch the song from the playlist on that offset position. Right?

Comment: http://www.sevenscript.net/myajax/index.html Use a similar method of pagination to this, only 50 results are returned at any one time. You wouldn't shuffle them on the client side, you'd send a request to the server that would return a shuffled playlist.

Comment: @roshkattu yep, i think that wud be the simplest solution.. of course with such an open ended problem you could fine tune your shuffle function to always return something thats already loaded or apply some fancy algo..There are many ways of solving this problem.. you will have to judge how complicated a solution you want..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think pagination is your best option. Just create a limit of 100 (for example) and use AJAX to extract the next 100. If the client turns on shuffle, just send another request to the server and let it call a function that does the following:

1. Count total rows in database
2. Use a randomize function to get 100 random numbers
3. Now create a slightly tricky query to get records from the db based
   on their rownumber:

function getRandomTracks($limit) {

```
  $total = $this->db->count_all('table_tracks');

  //Get random values. Speed optimization by predetermine random rownumbers using php

  $arr = array();
  while (count($arr) < $limit) { 
    $x = mt_rand(0, $total); //get random value between limit and 0
    if (!isset($arr[$x])) { //Random value must be unique
      //using random value as key and check using isset is faster then in_array
      $arr[$x] = true; 
    }
  }

  //Create IN string
  $in = implode(',', array_keys($arr));

  //Selection based on random rownumbers
  $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM
      (SELECT  @row := @row + 1 as row, t.*
         FROM `table_tracks` t, (SELECT @row := 0) r) AS tracks
     WHERE `row` IN(' . $in . ')');

  return $query->result();
```

}

I'm using a similar function, also to deal will large amounts of tracks (over 300.000) so I'm sure this will work!

Comment: WHY doesnt code tag work in my example.. tried to put it between code tags :/

Comment: Not it's working. Chris, I know this is a good way. I thought about this thing and I considered that would be the best way though to use. But I will call this shuffling every time a new song starts. Is this ok to use on any case, right?

Comment: Yes it is, You can skip the array and explode part if you are just needing 1 random record though

Comment: Thank you. This made my application go way more smooth than before. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

use ajax to load the data in steps of 100 (or more, just try)

do a loop over your recordsets and increase the limit each time:

```
<?php
$Step = 100;
$u_limit = 0;
$sql = "SELECT song_id FROM $MySQL_DB.songs";
$data = mysql_query($sql, $dblk);
$numer_of_entries = mysql_num_rows($data);
while($o_limit < $numnumer_of_entries)
{
    $o_limit = u_limit + $Step;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $MySQL_DB.songs order by id DESC LIMIT $u_limit, $o_limit";
    $data = mysql_query($sql, $dblk);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data))
    {
        // built an array and return this to ajax
    }
    $u_limit += $Step;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this reply. I will do so. I just needed to find out how to also handle the shuffling function properly

Comment: I'm not a fan of using queries in a loop. 100 songs might be acceptable (100 queries), but 1000 will produce 1000 queries and so on..

I suggest using my answer for the shuffle and my answer with a normal query to just get 100 records since its much faster..

Comment: give it a try, you dont need 1000 queries. in this case you need 5000/100 = 50! or you try it with a step of 500, 5000/500 = 10.

Comment: or you do 1 query, add it to an array (which is stored in a session-global-var $_SESSION) and iterate over this array in a step of 100. its just another possibility

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to load the "entire" data to client program even if you are using jQuery or other library else, as the key factor is not what code/sdk you are using but the browser itself!
By the way, chrome is the most fast and IE(before ver.10) is the lowest.

You can refer the links below:
http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/09/IE-Subsystems-Spends-Time
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/01/05/what-determines-that-a-script-is-long-running/
http://www.zdnet.com/browser-benchmarks-ie-firefox-opera-and-safari-3039420732/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb250448
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175500/en-us

So what you should do is to move your client logic to the server-side just as other people suggesting.

As you mentioned to get paginated but with just javascript for all your data, it is the same as none paginate in essence.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your post! This is a very good information for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://www.datatables.net/

I wonder but maybe it's works.

Comment: Let me check on this please. It might be very useful for what I need